# Use of volatile keyword in method signature in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Hey So I was examining the following code I found an online( https://javarevealed.wordpress.com/tag/initialization-on-demand-holder ) , which implements the Singelton design pattern using double checked locking like so:

```
public static volatile SingletonExample getSingletonInstance() {
        if (null == singletonInstance) {
            synchronized (SingletonExample.class){
                    if (null == singletonInstance) {
                         singletonInstance = new SingletonExample();
                     }
            }
        }
    return singletonInstance;
}
```

My question here is what is the point of having the volatile keyword in the method signature here? I thought the volatile modifier could be only be used on fields?

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't trust blog posts which can't even make it past Java syntax rules.

Comment: `volatile` is not a valid modifier for methods, it can only be used for fields. Just try it and see what error the compiler gives you. Eclipse says: _"Illegal modifier for the method SingletonExample; only public, protected, private, abstract, static, final, synchronized, native & strictfp are permitted"_

Comment: ok cool lesson learned about blogs! thanks guys